# Dose DB Reverse Engineering Plugin for Grails support secondary datasource?

Tags: grails, reverse-engineering

I use `DBReverseEngineering` Plugin handling existed database. This time, I have to set existed db as a secondary datasource, but that way the plugin can't find it.

I try to use environment setting as a workaround, like that:

```
environments:
  development:
    dataSources:
      dataSource:
        url: xxxxxx
      legacy01:
        url: zzzzzz
      legacy02:
        url: wwwwww
  test:
...
  production:
...
  reveng01:
    dataSource:
      url: zzzzzz
  reveng02:
    dataSource:
      rul: wwwwww



$ ./gradlew -Dgrails.env=reveng01 dbReverseEnginee
$ ./gradlew -Dgrails.env=reveng02 dbReverseEnginee
```

But it still means I got to add mapping in every generated domain classes, easy to forget. So, is there any way to make the plugin using a secondary datasource (legacy01/02 in this case). Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't supported, and I think I probably wouldn't add this as a feature (unless there is value in it beyond a somewhat rare use case). I can't know concrete details about how people use the plugin, but I've always assumed that it's more of an occasional utility, unlike many plugins which run whenever the app runs. It probably shouldn't have even been a plugin but instead a small desktop app (e.g. Griffon or JavaFX). Once you have domain classes mapped to your existing database I would think it would be rare to run the reverse-engineering script again except in rare cases.

If you do run the script somewhat regularly it should be easy enough to create a shell script or batch file with the correct configuration and use that, right?